# Remove in mongoose/mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm trying to add new function allowing to delete post for authorized users, so they can remove posts only they created. It works only with one statement, so I can allow them to delete all of their (only their) posts or delete selected posts, but of all users.
Heres code:

```
article_collection.remove({ _id: article_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id) }, {authoro: user}, function(error, result) {
```

When I add $and function, it does nothing, in the case posted above, it allows all users to delete any post.
I'm guessing I need to convert passed id of post to hex? but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both query conditions must be combined into a single object:

```
article_collection.remove({_id: id, authoro: user}, function(error, result) { ...
```

Comment: WOW, it does work. I tried every possible combination except this one :-). Thanks!